# Editing Om input properly with set :value

Tags: clojurescript, om

I need to display an input element with an initial value read from a cursor, but I don't need to update the cursor back when the user enters the new text. For example:

```
(defn my-comp [app owner]
  (reify
    om/IRender
    (render [_]
      (dom/div nil
               (dom/label nil "Enter text: ")
               (dom/input #js {:value (:text app)
                               :onChange #()}))))) ;; <- Why do I still need this?
```

I found that I always have to provide a function to the onChange event in order to let the input element update itself, at least an empty one. Is this the proper way to do this?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use :defaultValue instead of :value.

Thanks to this answer [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/clojurescript/WCeHLeNm324/Gv_oMUiG4RsJ)

Comment: For more information, this page in [React Documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#uncontrolled-components) is good reading.